# I get the following error when I add paging "IQueryable doesn't implement IAsyncQueryProvider"

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to implement paging for MVC .NetCore application. I have a list " List<_Item> Items which i got from azure blob" I get the following error when I add paging "IQueryable doesn't implement IAsyncQueryProvider"

Paging I'm trying to Implement:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Possible solutions I tried looking at:
https://github.com/romantitov/MockQueryable

HomeController:  Index function

```
[Obsolete]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string outletId, string contractId, string sort, string currentFilter, int? pageNumber)
        {
            ViewData["CurrentSort"] = sort;
            ViewData["OutletId"] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sort) ? "descending outletId" : "";
            ViewData["ContractId"] = sort == "ContractId" ? "descending contractId" : "ContractId";

            if (outletId != null || contractId != null)
            {
                pageNumber = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                outletId = currentFilter;
                contractId = currentFilter;
            }

            blobServices.Add_Tags_on_Blob("GSS_EDM_WorkHistoryTerminationsEngagementsIRP5Request_Dev.csv");
            // List<_Item> Items = (List<_Item>)blobServices.Get_BlobItem_List();

            List<_Item> Items = (List<_Item>)blobServices.Find_Blob_By_Tag(outletId, contractId);
            var records = Items.AsQueryable();

            switch (sort)
            {

                case "descending outletId":
                    records = records.OrderByDescending(x => x.OutletId);
                    break;

                case "descending contractId":
                    records = records.OrderByDescending(x => x.ContractId);
                    break;

                case "ContractId":
                    records = records.OrderBy(x => x.ContractId);
                    break;

                default:
                    records = records.OrderBy(x => x.OutletId);
                    break;

            }

            int pageSize = 3;
            return View(await PaginatedList<_Item>.CreateAsync(records, pageNumber ?? 1, pageSize));
            // return View(Items.ToPagedList(pageNumber ?? 1, 10));
        }
```

Paging Class[Lines of code with error HomeController

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xB32r.png)
[Lines of code with error; Pagging Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2PM7.png)

```
public class PaginatedList<T> : List<T>
    {
        public int PageIndex { get; private set; }
        public int TotalPages { get; private set; }

        public PaginatedList(List<T> items, int count, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
        {
            PageIndex = pageIndex;
            TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)pageSize);

            this.AddRange(items);
        }

        public bool HasPreviousPage
        {
            get
            {
                return (PageIndex > 1);
            }
        }

        public bool HasNextPage
        {
            get
            {
                return (PageIndex < TotalPages);
            }
        }

        public static async Task<PaginatedList<T>> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
        {
            var count = await source.CountAsync();
            var items = await source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
            return new PaginatedList<T>(items, count, pageIndex, pageSize);
        }
```

Comment: Any update? Does my reply help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error message, we could find `The provider for the source IQueryable doesn't implement IAsyncQueryProvider. Only providers that implement IAsyncQueryProvider can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations.`.

We couldn't  let `List<T>.AsQueryable()` to use `ToListAsync` method, since it doesn't implement the IAsyncQueryProvider.

To solve this issue, you could modify the `PaginatedList` method's `CreateAsync` method like below:

```
public static   PaginatedList<T> Create(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
{
    var count =   source.Count();
    var items =  source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();

    return new PaginatedList<T>(items, count, pageIndex, pageSize);
}
```

Usage:

```
return View( PaginatedList<_Item>.Create(records, pageNumber ?? 1, pageSize));
```

Comment: Thank you so much Brando, It worked perfectly 